# I²C between 2 Arduinos sends additional receive event

Tags: i2c, arduino-nano

I hooked up two Arduino Nanos with I²C, using 3 wires between GND <-> GND, A4 <-> A4, A5 <-> A5Ω and 1kΩ pull-up resistors on A4 & A5.

When I use the following code to communicate between them I get a weird empty receive event.

#### master.cpp

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define SERIAL_BAUD 9600

#define I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS 8

void setup () {
    Wire.begin();
    Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUD);
}

void getFromState (unsigned char state) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS);
    Serial.print("s");
    Serial.print(Wire.write(state));
    Serial.print("e");
    Serial.print(Wire.endTransmission());
    delay(5000);
    Wire.requestFrom(I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS, 2);
    int c = (unsigned char) Wire.read();
    Wire.flush();
    Serial.print("r");
    Serial.println(c);
    Wire.endTransmission();
}

void loop () {
    Serial.println("loop");
    getFromState(0);
    delay(10000);
    getFromState(1);
    delay(10000);
}
```

#### slave.cpp

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define SERIAL_BAUD 9600

#define I2C_ADDRESS 8

unsigned char state = 0;

void requestEvent () {
    Serial.print("Request ");
    Serial.println(state);
    Wire.write(state);
}

void receiveEvent (int amount) {
    Serial.print("a");
    Serial.print(amount);
    Serial.print("r");
    state = (unsigned char) Wire.read();
    Serial.println(state);
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUD);
    Wire.begin(I2C_ADDRESS);
    Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
    Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
}

void loop() {
    delay(10);
}
```

#### Serial Output Master After 1.5 Loops

```
loop
s1e0r0
s1e0r1
loop
s1e0r0
s1e0
```

#### Serial Output Slave After 1.5 Loops

```
a1r0
Request 0
a0r255
a1r1
Request 0
a0r255
a1r0
Request 0
a0r255
a1r1
```

#### Question

Why is there an empty receive event `a0r255` after every request? Is that normal? Am I doing something wrong? Is this some sort of hardware issue?

EDIT: I opensourced this project [here](https://github.com/dodekeract/arduino-examples/tree/master/custom-i2c-device), take a look if you want to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main culprit that is causing your problem is the second

```
Wire.endTransmission();
```

after your `requestFrom`.  That causes the previous `startTransmission()` to be repeated with no data in it - thus giving you a second `receiveEvent` call with no data.

Comment: That's a quite weird behavior, but sounds like it could truly be the reason this happens. Will have to check this out tomorrow moring since it's quite late in Germany already. :(

Comment: It's late here in the UK too, but I'm still firing on all cylinders ;)

Comment: yeah I know that feel, I sometimes try not to stay up that long, today is one of these days where I may get a reasonable bedtime.

Comment: Thanks, this actually was the reason I was seeing the empty packets. Accepting this answer, since it is more tailored towards the actual problem. Doesn't mean I don't appreciate the other one a lot, but this solved & explained the "real" issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several issues:

For the master:

- Your I2C transactions should be quick and not delayed with `Serial.print()`s like in `getFromState()`
- You requested 2 bytes from the slave but you are reading only one from the buffer. `Wire.flush()` flushes the *outgoing* buffer, not the receive buffer. Use `while (Wire.read() != -1);` instead.
- Its also advised that you use `Wire.available()` to iterate through the receive buffer when `read()`ing; its how you check if anything was received at all and how many bytes were received.
- After using `requestFrom()`, you shouldn't call `endTransmission()`. Its self-contained.

For the slave:

- You should never call `Serial.print()` or `delay()` in `requestEvent()` or `receiveEvent()`; both functions are called from within ISRs and ISRs are meant to execute quickly and return.
- You are requesting 2 bytes from the slave in your master code, whereas your slave's `requestEvent()` writes only one byte.
- In `receiveEvent()`, again its best to use either `Wire.available()` to iterate through the RX buffer or you use the variable `amount`. This way, you read everything in the buffer; you can also flush the RX buffer like I showed you before.

Finally those delays are rather long; 10ms would do, if they are even needed at all.

Comment: Most of these issues are in the code for debugging purposes (serial and ultra long delays so I can actually see whats happening) The thing with 2 bytes is: as soon as I set it to one, it doesn't work anymore, it just stops. The endTransmission is an accident/leftover from code I previously used, will check if any of this changes anything tomorrow morning. I literally tried to debug this code for hours, so I tested a lot of things, one initial issue actually was that I needed the pull ups because otherwise the slave couldn't send anything to the master (except. somehow ACK bits).

Comment: Accepted the other answer, because it had a better explanation and was more precisely addressing the actual problem. Thanks for your input nevertheless, if possible I'd accept yours too. :(